# Missing field in drupal search api solr index

Tags: php, drupal, solr

I'm having a problem with 2 or 3 fields disappearing from drupal search api solr index.

**For example:** I have a *field_description*, I mark it as indexed and set whole index for reindexing. Everything works fine and I can search by this field.

However after some (random) amount of time I just can't search by it anymore, and the field also disappears from the list on **admin/config/search/search_api/index/node_search/fields**.

Any idea what could I do or at least where to start searching?

I'm using PHP 5.6 and drupal version 7.52 with all modules updated to the latest suggested version.

*Note:* I have quite a lot of fields ~ 120 fields, and in my index I have approximately 100.000 nodes.

Comment: Can you check the document in the Solr admin console to see if the field is present in the document there?

Comment: Yes in solr admin console I see this field.

Comment: The field should not disappear for no reasons from the field list, or do you mean he is becoming unchecked?
If so, do you use Features? A feature could be removing the manual configuration of your index when reverting it for others reasons... .

Comment: Well the field actualy dissapears from this list after cache clear it appears back but as unchecked. And my features module is disabled.

Comment: Are you using varnish , memcache ? maybe cache can make this kind of issue

Comment: Well yes we are using memcache and varnish. I will now try it on a server without memcache and varnish to see if it works there. Thanks for the idea, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have auto updates with solr search? It could case your
  problem.
- Memcache works bad with search reindex turn off it if you could, it can case some data missing.
   Debug your query's you could not get new values but Memcache could provide old one:

> https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004454253-Using-Solr-Devel-module-to-debug-Acquia-Search-indexing-and-queries

- Check your data from db or console with drush, not from UI.
- Recheck that you definitely save information after reindex and it gets into db.
- Check solr admin UI are there any problems in logs?